# Calling a function from a function undeclared identifier

Tags: solidity, contract-invocation

I get an error message on the line returnString("testing"); that says:

DeclarationError: Undeclared identifier.
        returnString("testing");

```
function returnString (string checkers) external view returns(string) {
    return checkers;
}

function getBidders() public {
    returnString("testing"); 
}
```

Why wont this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because you are calling `returnString` function, declared as `external` from internal, declared as `public` function. Declare `returnString` function as `public` instead since you are calling it from inside.

```
function returnString (string checkers) public view returns(string) {
    return checkers;
}
```

Look at [this](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/32464/33958) answer for reference.