# what does external means ? how can i call the test2() inside my class

Tags: solidity, remix

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.7;

    contract Test {
        function test() public view  returns (uint){
             return 10*10;
        }

        function test2() external view  returns (uint){
             return 10*2;
        }
    }
```

1) according to my knowledge external means we cannot call the function inside class but how i am able to call it ?

Can any one please explain? This is my output which i can see in remix console.

```
 status     0x1 Transaction mined and execution succeed
 transaction hash   0x0e3c9b7c67387cdcf3a4d2001323e83b20f64dbe12abb6e81700ccc6cc844454
 from   0xca35b7d915458ef540ade6068dfe2f44e8fa733c
 to     Test.test2() 0x0dcd2f752394c41875e259e00bb44fd505297caf
 gas    3000000 gas

 transaction cost   21463 gas 
 execution cost     191 gas 
 hash   0x0e3c9b7c67387cdcf3a4d2001323e83b20f64dbe12abb6e81700ccc6cc844454
 input  0x66e...41cb7
 decoded input  {}
 decoded output     {
    "0": "uint256: 20"
}
 logs   []
 value 

0 wei
```

Comment: This "question" (title and body) is unreadable!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between an internal/external and public/private function in solidity?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/32353/what-is-the-difference-between-an-internal-external-and-public-private-function)

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can: `this.test2()` instead of just `test2`. But notice that `msg.sender` will be changed to `this`.

`public` = `internal` + `external`